# Can the statistics on the 'About Stack Exchange' page be updated?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange.com, tour, network-statistics

If you scroll down the '[About Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/about)' page, you will find some statistics for the network.

[image: SE site statistics]

Since these statistics are from 2014, they are… *a little bit* out of date.

Well, more than a little bit: [StackOverflow alone just reached 10 million questions](https://stackoverflow.com/10m) - which means these statistics are *already* millions of questions off, without even beginning to count those from other sites in the network.

Since the network has reached a big milestone with SO's 10m questions, I think now would be a great time to update these stats.

Some stats that really need updating:

- Registed SO users - about 1 million off
- Questions - about 8-9 million off
- Answers - about 15 million off
- Edits, Comments and Votes - 100 million off on *SO alone*
- Visits - Almost 2 BILLION off on SO alone *in the past year!*
- Pageviews - Let's not even go there.....

**So, can we please have these statistics updated?**

Comment: I suspect the stats are excluding Stack Overflow. Whether a bug or by design, not my place to say. (so the feature request should be "include SO in SE Network Stats")

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't know, these stats are from 2014 after all.

Comment: Looks like the stats are not **from** 2014, but **only for** 2014: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3928706#3928706

Comment: @ShadowWizard It does say "2014" in the title directly above the stats. :) That aside, 2015 isn't over yet. Still got a few more months to go. Once 2016 rolls around these numbers will get updated, probably just to 2015 numbers.

Comment: Now the *2018 Stack Exchange Network Overview* is updated in the [SE About](https://stackexchange.com/about) page.

Comment: @MonicaCellio since when have you been a moderator here?

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain about an hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page has been updated with 2018 stats (January 2019 for SO):

[image: 2019 screenshot]

Comment: I believe there's also a plan to update these quarterly as well, but I don't remember where I heard that.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the statistics on this page that I'm aware of, but it does seem like a confusing design error.

I know lots of users, including me, were confused with the way this design was when that page was first launched/redesigned like this. The way the horizontal lines and title category are spaced a user could easily mistaken the number for the title below but not above the number. I think it'd be better to just remove the horizontal separators and put the title closer to the number. There's countless ways to better design this page.

They could have used some bold at least somewhere in the 2014 SE network statistics title.. to make that stand out more.

> Since these statistics are from 2014, they are..... a little..... bit out of date.

Like others have stated in the comments, these statistics are not out of date, since the statistics are not including data from prior to 2014 or after 2014, but only data that occurred in 2014.

So far example, Stack Overflow was launched in 2008. The 3.1 million questions asked does not include questions asked in 2008 through 2013, nor 2015. It only includes the questions asked in 2014.

Same with other stats, only counting those actions that occurred in the year of 2014.